# c# - Save DataGridView After filter

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to save the data of the `DataGridView` filtered by `ComboBox` and save it in a new `DataGridView` in order to display it in an existing chart entered by the first `DataGridView`.

```
(datagridview1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("ID = '{0}'",combobox1.SelectionItem.ToString());
```

How do i save the `DataGridView1` in a new one with the filtered data ?
Thanks
Roy

Comment: Let me know if the following thread was helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17349535/updating-database-using-datagrid-in-c-sharp

Comment: Hi ,  i need to save the data in a new datagridview  after it been filtered by the the attched code